# Why does NSString method UTF8String causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passed to function ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel()?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I first wrote

```
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phone, numValue, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL)
```

it crashed with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS
[image]

After I changed the code to

```
CFStringRef numValue = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, [numStr UTF8String], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phone, numValue, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL)
```

it goes right. Why? The function ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel is declared:
[image]

the parameter value is CFTypeRef, aka, const void *, so I think passing to it a const char * is correct. But the compiler doesn't think so...

Comment: You think wrong; `CFTypeRef` is *opaque*, hence it's defined as `const void *`.  That does not mean you can pass `const char *`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but that doesn't explain why it gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Comment: Yes it does.  You are not providing the correct type.

Comment: OK, I'll try to understand that. Thanks!